# Capturing modifier keys Qt

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-events

I am trying to understand how to handle various events with Qt and have found an issue I cannot understand with key modifiers e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> etc. I have made a default Qt GUI Application in Qt Creator extending QMainWindow and have found that the following example does not produce understandable results.

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Modifier " << event->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier);
    qDebug() << "Key " << event->key();
    qDebug() << "Brute force " << (event->key() == Qt::Key_Control);
}
```

Using the modifiers() function on the event never is true while the brute force method returns the correct value.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using this to check for shift:

`if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier){...}`

this to check for control:

`if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier){...}`

and so on. That works well for me.

EDIT:

To get the modifiers of a wheel event, you need to check the `QWheelEvent` object passed to your `wheelEvent()` method:

```
void MainWindow::wheelEvent( QWheelEvent *wheelEvent )
{
    if( wheelEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier )
    {
        // do something awesome
    }
    else if( wheelEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier )
    {
        // do something even awesomer!
    }
}
```

Comment: It would seem the plot thickens. The modifiers only work when another key is pressed e.g. if I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> the if statements you suggest will not be true. If I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Any</kbd> the shift modifier works. The tests are being performed on OSX 10.8.4 which may effect this...

Comment: Further testing shows that testing using
`if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)`
and any other modifiers only works within the keyPressEvent, and again only works properly when another key is struck in conjunction with the modifier. The end goal is to have this work in an eventFilter for wheel events but this does not work at all for that.

Comment: It seems to be working on one of the test computers, I need to try it on my other test computer as I could have sworn I had tried the updated answer already.

Comment: Tested the code on the other computer and discovered something interesting. The setup is a Macbook Pro hooked to an external monitor and keyboard/mouse. The modifiers only work when using the touch pad is used to scroll but not when the external mouse wheel is used.

Comment: @user29291 Very interesting indeed.  I've never considered how Qt addresses multiple mice/keyboards.  This is definitely something to keep in mind!

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation, `QKeyEvent::modifiers`  cannot always be trusted. Try to use `QApplication::keyboardModifiers()` static function instead.

---

From [Qt 5 Doc. – Qt::KeyboardModifiers QKeyEvent::modifiers() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#modifiers):

> **Warning:** This function cannot always be trusted. The user can confuse it by pressing both **Shift** keys simultaneously and releasing one of them, for example.

Comment: I was using this with a Macbook Pro with an external mouse and keyboard and found that the modifiers only work when using the touch pad on the laptop but not the wheel on the external mouse.

Comment: care to add a link or some more information as to what documentation says that "`QKeyEvent::modifiers` cannot always be trusted" ?

Comment: can't trust QKeyEvent::modifiers - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#modifiers

Comment: Interesting.  Here's what I get when pressing the a shift key:
`Key press: 0x1000020 with QApplication::keyboardModifiers() = 0x0 and event->modifiers = 0x2000000`

Here's what I get pressing both Shift keys:
`Key press: 0x1000020 with QApplication::keyboardModifiers() = 0x2000000 and event->modifiers = 0x0`

Here's Shift + 1 (regardless of how many Shift keys I'm holding down):
`Key press: 0x21 with QApplication::keyboardModifiers() = 0x2000000 and event->modifiers = 0x2000000` 

(Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Qt 5.15)