# Qt keyboard modifier shift key along with another keypress not being detected

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5

```
if(e->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier && e->key() == Qt::Key_H)
```

This if statement is not executing. Could someone please point out the issue ?

I am trying to detect shift + h keypress in Qt `keyPressEvent()`. I am using qt 5.9

Key event is detected but if statement does not evaluate to true.

I cant get the code to go into the if statement. I am on a Mac OS X el capitan

Comment: Is the event executed?

Comment: yeah.. the if statement isnt working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing modifier keys Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204142/capturing-modifier-keys-qt)

Comment: Change `if(e->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier && e->key() == Qt::Key_H)` to `if((e->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) && e->key() == Qt::Key_H)`

Comment: didnt work. It looks like this

`if((e->modifiers() & Qt::KeyboardModifier::ShiftModifier) && e->key() == Qt::Key_H)`

Answer (score 2):

`e->key()` can not handle the case difference.

If you use `e->key()` ---- `SHIFT+H` and `SHIFT+h` (By caps lock in windows) , both are same.

If you want to handle `SHIFT+h` (Small 'h') specifically then go with `e->text()`.

Try something like below (tested on Windows by applying CAPS LOCK):

```
if (e->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier && e->text() == QString('h'))
{
    QString str = e->text();
    std::cout << str.toLatin1().data() << endl;
}
```

Comment: It actually didnt work. I had to go with: `if(e->text() == QString('H'))`.

Thanks for the ideas though.